# Radiobuttons wont go next to text

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have two customized radiobuttons next to eachother. But its 3rd in a block with fore types and titles. Both have `display: inline-block;` in the css but still the radio buttons go under the text block. I don't know how to get them next to eachother like the rest.

```css
/*radio button yes no*/
.switch-field {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 40px;
 overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 225px;
}



.switch-field input {
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field label {
  float: left;
}

.switch-field label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #b70000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:      all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition:         all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked + label {
  background-color: #b70000;;
 color:white;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 0px 0px 0;
}
/*radio button yes no*/

/*block*/
.block label { display: inline-block; width: 140px; text-align: right; }
```

```html
<div class="CalculatorLeft" style="padding-left: 29px;"id="alles">
  <h2 style="color:#b70000;">Bereken Prijs</h2>
  <div class="block">
      <label>Aantal vierkante meters</label>
      <input type="text" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 92px;width:200px;" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
      <label>V-naden aanwezig</label>
      <select name="cars" class="" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 128px;width:200px;">
        <option value="behandeling" selected>Soort behandeling</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
      <label>Soort behandeling</label>
      <div class="switch-field">
        <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" checked/>
        <label for="switch_left">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" />
        <label for="switch_right">No</label>
      </div>
  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
      <label>Postcode & Huisnummer</label>
      <input type="text" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 89px;width:200px;" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please use code snippets if possible. People are much more likely to help if they don't have to tediously copy-paste your code and see what it's doing in the first place.

Comment: Hi J.Coderino, could you please elaborate what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to make the red rectangle with "yes/no" to be on the same height as the text left of it stating "soort behandeling"? P.S. Dutch is amazing. https://jsfiddle.net/xnz0dg4r/

Comment: @barrosy Yes that is what im trying to do. So all the text have something on the right of it. And thanks haha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to remove any margin and padding on the parent element of the "yes/no" radio inputs as this "container" is causing the element to move away from the label.

See snippet for solution:

```css
/*radio button yes no*/

.switch-field {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  /*padding: 40px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /*margin-left: 225px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.switch-field input {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field label {
  float: left;
}

.switch-field label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #b70000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked+label {
  background-color: #b70000;
  ;
  color: white;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 0px 0px 0;
}


/*radio button yes no*/

.block label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="CalculatorLeft" style="padding-left: 29px;" id="alles">
  <h2 style="color:#b70000;">Bereken Prijs</h2>
  <div class="block">
    <label>Aantal vierkante meters</label>
    <input type="text" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 92px;width:200px;" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
    <label>V-naden aanwezig</label>
    <select name="cars" class="" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 128px;width:200px;">
      <option value="behandeling" selected>Soort behandeling</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
    <label>Soort behandeling</label>
    <div class="switch-field">
      <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" checked/>
      <label for="switch_left">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" />
      <label for="switch_right">No</label>
    </div>
  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
    <label>Postcode & Huisnummer</label>
    <input type="text" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 89px;width:200px;" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Take a look at your `.switch-field` class for changes. You could add a margin-top to it as well to position it correctly. If you need any more help please do let me know.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dk6jbrp/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

**CSS**

```
.switch-field {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 95px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/18fhpw3j/)**

Comment: I think your fiddle url does not contain the solution you posted here above.

Comment: @Barrosy, sorry my mistake, the url was fixed

Comment: I see, just adding `vertical-align: middle` would've been a perfect fit in my answer.